# Regex help needed?

Tags: regex

I've been strugling with this for quite a while now,
How can i match just a chemical formula fro the string bellow:

```
<formula concise="C 20 H 21 N 7 O 7"/>
```

ex: need C20H21N7O7

i tried :

```
<formula concise=.([\w\s\d]+).\/>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

PS: need general case that can be used to find other formulas

Comment: You (probably) need to escape the final `/`: https://regex101.com/r/mxLu5n/1

Comment: Please do some efforts to write your question. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`<formula concise="([\w\s\d]+)"\/>`

The first capture group will get you the string in between the quotes of the `concise` attribute.